# centos azure vm with broken firewall

Tags: azure, ssh, console, centos, firewall

I accidently broke my centos VM in azure by twiddling firewall rules within it. After a reboot, the normal ssh access is not working anymore. Is there any chance to get into that VM, any console login directly to the machine somehow?

Comment: Was it deployed using the new Resources Manager or Classic?

Comment: @haim770 via Resources Manager

Comment: Is `VMAccessForLinux` installed as a VM extension (https://github.com/Azure/azure-linux-extensions/tree/master/VMAccess)?

Comment: As I did not heard of such, possibly not. But reading the feature list of the extension you posted, as far as I can see it relies on SSH login to the box. The misconfigured firewall within the machine is blocking such requests though. Seems that dumping the box is the single solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the current state (April 2016) at microsoft about this, I've decided to dump the virtual machine and set it up again:

> This one-directional access is just a start. Console screenshots and serial output can help identify a problem, but they are not the solution for resolving the problems. We are working on enhancements that will enable secure bi-directional access to the console of the virtual machine. This will enable additionally debugging capabilities, and, more importantly, the ability to resolve a set of common problems through the bi-directional access. Right now, I don’t have a timeline but we know this is critical.

([article](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/3761826-virtual-machine-console-access?page=2&per_page=20))